# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 521 for URL:

Tags: java, http, browser

I want to crawl the data of a URL "http://www.gc-zb.com/index/index.html"
but When I operate like this I got the error:

```
public class InvitedBids {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        InputStream inputStream=null;
        HttpURLConnection httpConn=null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader=null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;
        StringBuilder contentBuf=null;
        String myURL="http://www.gc-zb.com/index/index.html";
        URL url= null;
        try {
            url = new URL(myURL);
            System.out.println(url);
            httpConn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            inputStream=httpConn.getInputStream();  //error occurs
            inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"utf-8"); 
            bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); 
            String line="";
            contentBuf=new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {  
                contentBuf.append(line);
            }
            String buf=contentBuf.toString();
            System.out.println(buf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
           //close I/O and HTTP
        }

    }
}
```

the console says:

```
http://www.gc-zb.com/index/index.html
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 521 for URL: http://www.gc-zb.com/index/index.html
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.feilong.bid.InvitedBids.main(InvitedBids.java:43)
```

Anybody who knows how to solve it .Thank you!

Comment: 521 Web Server Is Down
The origin server has refused the connection from Cloudflare. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

Like Jon said earlier, error 521 means that the server is down. so don't worry and wait until the server is up. [cloudflare docs](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171916-Error-521-Web-server-is-down)

btw, if you want to crawl documents, I strongly suggest you to use JSOUP to get your data. we use it at my company and it rulz.

ex:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
String title = doc.title();
```

docs:
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Recommended Use 
      org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
To solve the problem